# Dynamically accessing Mongodb database collection based in URL parameters

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mern

I have an API endpoint as **api/get?subject=economics**, and based on this subject parameter I access various database collections in mongodb. Right now I am using switch case statements to access the required database based on subject parameters. This is making my code very lengthy. Is there a way to access the database just by the subject parameter value? for example, instead of using this

```js
const {subject}=req.query
switch (subject)
case "economics"
const data= await economics.find() 
break;
```

I want to be able to use this

```js
const {subject}=req.query
const data=await subject.find() // here subject will refrence its value like economics or stats
```

Comment: have you tried?

Comment: Yes it give error **subject.find()** is not a function

Comment: You have to pass the variable to `db()` or soomething similar. chec the docs

Answer (score 0):

I think better way to pass modal as an argument. Here I is the code, How I have created common controller

https://gist.github.com/RMUSMAN/b7132fda6e945393882586c26b132e24

https://gist.github.com/RMUSMAN/c419d8149effb8514845946ad5b652f1

https://gist.github.com/RMUSMAN/f44ba2a20da35a2ce5ffd7517ea8fca8